# How to repeat code with cell offsets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies for the simple question in advance. I am new to VBA.

I have the following sample data in excel:

[image: Sample Data]

I would like to copy the X, Y and Z values for Points 1 to 5 and locate them in the same row as the values 30, 40, 50...etc values. I have written the following code which copies one set of points 1-5 next to 30, how to I apply this again to 40, 50...etc. My entire data set goes well beyond 50, so automating is key.

```
Sub MoveCopyCells()

Range(Cells(26, 2), Cells(26, 4)).Copy Range(Cells(24, 2), Cells(24, 4))
Range(Cells(27, 2), Cells(27, 4)).Copy Range(Cells(24, 11), Cells(24, 13))
Range(Cells(28, 2), Cells(28, 4)).Copy Range(Cells(24, 14), Cells(24, 16))
Range(Cells(29, 2), Cells(29, 4)).Copy Range(Cells(24, 17), Cells(24, 19))
Range(Cells(30, 2), Cells(30, 4)).Copy Range(Cells(24, 26), Cells(24, 28))

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to know how to loop?  Look up loops in VBA.

Comment: Also, no need to copy and paste, you can just say `range("b26:d30").value=range("b2:d6").value`

Comment: Better yet, copy entire tables `Range("B26").Resize(4,3).Value = Range("B2").Resize(4,3).Value`. This way you ensure equal size tables, and don't have to worry about row & column numbers for the table end values.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy multiple values by expanding the reference range from a single cell to a table (multiple rows and columns) using the `.Resize()` function.

Also the source cells are nicely arranged by row, but the destination cells aren't. So the destination column offsets can be stored in a array for use in a loop.

```
Sub BetterCopyCells()

    Dim col_offset() As Variant, i As Long
    col_offset = Array(0, 9, 12, 15, 24)

    For i = 0 To 4
        Range("B24").Offset(0, col_offset(i)).Resize(1, 3).Value2 = _
            Range("B26").Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value2
    Next i

End Sub
```

The general process is of the form

```
Range("Top Left of Destination").Resize(noRows,noCols).Value2 = _
    Range("Top Left of Source").Resize(noRows,noCols).Value2
```

You can move from an absolute reference like `Range("B2")` to a relative location using `.Cells()` or `.Offset()`. The following two references have the exact same result

```
Range("B2").Cells(10,3)  ' => points to "D11"
Range("B2").Offset(9,2)  ' => points to "D11"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations, but it's faster to switch to array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim vR As Variant
    r = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To r Step 8
        Set rng = Range("a" & i)
        vR = TransData(rng)
        rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 27) = vR
    Next i

End Sub
Function TransData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim vDB, vR(1 To 27)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim c As Variant

    c = Array(1, 10, 13, 16, 25)

    vDB = rng.Offset(2, 1).Resize(5, 3)
    For i = 0 To 4
        For j = 1 To 3
            vR(c(i) + j - 1) = vDB(i + 1, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    TransData = vR
End Function
```